# Visualizing multiple time series with a second time dimension

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I have a number of time series, around 10~20. There is a primary time series and each of the other series represents an offset (lead or lag) from this series. Note that this lead or lag is not a lead/lag of the observed time series value but an offset of the underlying variable

$$y_{t}^{0} = f_{t}(x_{t})$$
$$y_{t}^{-1} = f_{t}(x_{t-1})$$
$$y_{t}^{-2} = f_{t}(x_{t-2})$$
$$y_{t}^{+1} = f_{t}(x_{t+1})$$

I am trying to think of a good way to visualize this. One attempt I had come up with was to use color as the lead/lag dimension, such as

[image]

I expect a roughly monotonic decrease in the series associated with increasing lags and a similarly roughly monotonic increases in the series associated with leads. A series which would be poorly behaved would look like the following picture.
[image]

As you can see the green and red lines are all intermixed, showing this monotonic property is not present. While this roughly accomplishes what I was setting out to do I don't find these graphs particularly easy to read / interpret.

**Question**

Are there new graphics that could represent this information or ideas on modifications (blending etc.) to the current charts to make them easier to interpret.

Comment: You could take a look at contour boxplots, as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_boxplot